# Find the solutions of $x$ such that $\arcsin x=2\arctan x$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, inverse-function, fake-proofs

Find the solutions of $x$ such that $\arcsin x=2\arctan x.$

My solution goes  like this:

> We have, $\arcsin x=2\arctan x.$ Now, $2\arctan x=\arctan(\frac{2x}{{1-x^2}})=\arcsin(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}).$ Now, $$\arctan(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})=\arcsin (\frac{2x}{1+x^2})=\arcsin x\implies x=(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}).$$ Thus, the possible values of $x$ are $0,1,-1.$

However, if we solve this, using this approach, we find only one solution :

> We have, $\arcsin x=2\arctan x.$ Now, $2\arctan x=\arctan(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})$ and $\arcsin x=\arctan (\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}).$ Thus, $\arctan (\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})=\arctan(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})\implies (\frac{2x}{{1-x^2}})=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}).$ Now, $x=0$ is the only solution of it. For if, $x\neq 0$, then $1-x^2=4,$ a contradiction.

I don't get what's wrong with this second approach ? Which of the two methods are valid ? If one is invalid, then why is it so ? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 Does that matter?

Comment: @PlaceReporter99  How ?

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 Yes, but I think, in this case, it doesn't matter...

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 It doesn't matter, since the the $\arcsin$ and $\arctan$ functions "in degrees" is just $\frac{180}{\pi} \arcsin(x)$ and $\frac{180}{\pi} \arctan(x)$, so the equation is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $2\arctan x=\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$ is valid only for $x \in (-1,1)$. It's clear that it's not valid, for example, for $x=1$ since the RHS is undefined.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Franklin Plug $x=1$ into the arctan expression and you get division by zero

Comment: The equality is false for $x=1$. The LHS is $2 \arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$, but the RHS is $\arctan\left(\frac{2\cdot 1}{ 1-1^2}\right) = \arctan(2/0)$

Comment: @jjagmath But then both the solutions, are wrong ?

Comment: @jjagmath Also, which solution you are talking about?

Comment: @jjagmath I used the identity in both the solutions!

Comment: Yes, both are wrong, since both use the identity.

Comment: @jjagmath Then what will the "real method" ?

Comment: As usual in Mathematics, there's no "**the** solution". One posible way is to observe that  the identities you used are valid for $x \in (-1,1)$ and deal with the exceptional points $x=1$ and $x=-1$ separately.

Comment: I don't need to follow that link since is way easier to simply **check the solutions**: $\arcsin(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $2\arctan(1) = 2\frac{\pi }{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: $\arcsin()$ cannot take values in those intervals.

Comment: $\arcsin$ is not even defined outside $[-1 ,1]$ (or are you looking for non-real solutions?)

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks a lot! I do get it now!

Answer (score 0):

By inspection  $x=0$ is a solution. Outside the x- interval $\pm 1$  there are no real solutions because sin, cos are bounded within unity absolute value.

To me appears there is no reason why a direct trig solution would not furnish all solutions.

We write

$$ \tan^{-1} x = \theta ;~  \sin^{-1}x = 2\theta$$

Take sin of second part

$$ x= 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta $$

[image]

$$ x= 2 \cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

So

$$ \to x= 0,~2 =1+x^2, \to x= \pm 1; $$

which are the only complete real three solutions.

Answer (score -1):

$\arcsin(x)=2\arctan(x)$

$\sin (\arcsin(x))= \sin (2 \arctan x)=x$

Let $u=\arctan x\implies x= \tan u\implies \cos{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\implies \sin u= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

$x=\sin(2\arctan x)=2\sin(\arctan{x})\cos(\arctan(x))=2\sin{u}\cos{u}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

$x=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\implies x \in \{0,1,-1 \}$